# Parsing nested objects in FIT

Tags: java, fit-framework

I am using Framework for Integrated Test. I know how to use `ColumnFixture`, `RowFixture` and `ActionFixture` basically. Now my problem is, if I have nested objects like `Customer` object is holding `Address` object with some fields, how can I parse such kind of objects.

ex:

```
        package com.sample;

        import java.sql.Date;

        public class Customer {
            private String name;
            private int no;
            private Date dob;
            private Address address;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public int getNo() {
                return no;
            }

            public void setNo(int no) {
                this.no = no;
            }

            public Date getDob() {
                return dob;
            }

            public void setDob(Date dob) {
                this.dob = dob;
            }

            public Address getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            public void setAddress(Address address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Customer [name=" + name + ", no=" + no + ", dob=" + dob
                        + ", address=" + address + "]";
            }

        }
        package com.sample;

        public class Address {
            private int dno;
            private String street;
            private String city;

            public int getDno() {
                return dno;
            }

            public void setDno(int dno) {
                this.dno = dno;
            }

            public String getStreet() {
                return street;
            }

            public void setStreet(String street) {
                this.street = street;
            }

            public String getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(String city) {
                this.city = city;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Address [dno=" + dno + ", street=" + street + ", city=" + city
                        + "]";
            }
        }
```

Now, in my my fixture, I want to check (using `ActionFixture`) `getCustomer()` method that returns customer object. Now in the `parse(String s, Type)` where 's' is string format of customer object coming from input file, how can I convert it into `Customer` object.

Is my approach proper?

Comment: If you don't want a lot of `spam`, remove your email from `public` forum.